# I'm trying to make an S3 Bucket as private as possible while still allowing views and uploads from a specific website domain. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Here is my current S3 Bucket Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name-s3-private/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": "https://my-website-name.com/*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This Policy is meant to allow people to perform GET and PUT actions as long as the request is coming from a certain domain.  Please note: I am aware that `aws:Referer` is not perfectly secure, and frankly I do not care. Nor do I want to set up temporary IAM accounts or access points.

I only want to restrict most people from easily viewing this content.

Once the Policy was set, I made my Bucket Privacy settings look like this, to keep the Bucket as private as possible but still have it honor my just-written Policy:

[image]

**The desired effect:** Stops people from viewing or uploading files, UNLESS they are doing so through my website.

**The actual effect:**  This DOES allow people to view files on-site, and prevents off-site viewing. That's good.

However, when I try to upload to the Bucket from a form on the site, I still get the Access Denied XML despite the action being approved in the policy.

I also have all my CORS stuff enabled for this domain if it matters.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. I've been staring at this for too long.

Comment: Voting to close without a comment isn't helpful. This question has a clearly stated problem, and a clearly stated desirable outcome. There's a body of code that I have tried, and that partially works. What more do you need?

Comment: If you temporarily remove the `Referer` condition, does the form work like you expect? If so, it might be the the browser is not providing a `referer` when the form is being submitted.

Answer (score 1):

> The desired effect: Stops people from viewing or uploading files, UNLESS they are doing so through my website.

Its **not possible** with your setup.  Anyone can upload anything to your bucket, and `aws:Referer` is easily spoofed.

Thus, your policy and bucket are examples of **extremely** bad setup due to having `s3:PutObject` which is allowed to everyone.

The proper way is to due to through [S3 pre-signed urls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html), cloudfront or custom backend.

In addition you should setup full authentication and authorization on your website, so that only trusted users can upload things directly.